# How to get "classicthesis.sty" in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, classicthesis

I am trying to compile a .tex file using texstudio in Ubuntu, and it says 
`File 'classicthesis.sty' not found. ^^M`. I have already installed the `texlive-full` package. How to get this package?

Comment: Exactly which Ubuntu Texlive version do you have? They tend to be out of date.

Comment: On ubuntu 18.04 it seems to come from `texlive-publishers` (located via the `apt-file` feature). Though, I do not use TeXLive from Ubuntu, I use the up to date upstream version

Comment: It's usually enough to have the .sty file in the same directory where your .tex is. No need to install anything, just get the sty from bitbucket.

Comment: `texlive-publishers` has been part of/a dependency of `texlive-full` since at least Ubuntu 9.04 (i.e., 10 years ago) and `classicthesis.sty` is in `texlive-publishers` since at least 2012 as far as I could find. So maybe there is another issue with your installation. Do you actually have the file (for example in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/classicthesis`, or elsewhere)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the installation of textlive-full was interrupted and the file `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/classicthesis` was missing . The problem was solved after running `sudo apt --fix-broken install`.

As mentioned in the comments, installing the package `texlive-publishers` will enable this (no need to install `texlive-full`)